# Why does GCC 10 mfence no more STD Atomic operations? Is it sufficient enough by the memory Model?

Tags: c++, assembly, gcc, memory-barriers, stdatomic

I discovered currently that GCC 10 will no more use the `mov` and `mfence` method and instead will use the implied lock by an `xchg`. Is this sufficient by the memory model to not break any stuff when using multithreading?

As an example I tried on godbolt first with gcc 9.3 and then with gcc 10.2 was the following Code (as optimization I used -O2):

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <atomic>

std::atomic_int32_t    idx;

int32_t increment(void) 
{
    return idx = (idx + 1);
}
```

The results were the following:

GCC 9.3:

```
increment():
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR idx[rip]
        add     eax, 1
        mov     DWORD PTR idx[rip], eax
        mfence
        ret
idx:
        .zero   4
```

GCC 10.2:

```
increment():
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR idx[rip]
        add     eax, 1
        mov     edx, eax
        xchg    edx, DWORD PTR idx[rip]
        ret
idx:
        .zero   4
```

Could someone enlight me or just point me to the right point in the programming manual.

With best regards

**Edit:**
Ok the part with the memory model is answered by the two mentioned threads.

But the other question was: Why it changed now with gcc 10? The issues mentioned about skylake etc. are also a few days old.

Comment: Are you expecting the increment to be atomic? You have combined two atomic operations into a non-atomic operation.

Comment: That's not my point of interest. In the assembly generated the result was first a mfence which locked the load store ordering and now with gcc 10 it is implemented as xchg (which locks implicitly when operating on memory).

Comment: GCC changed to `xchg` because it's faster than `mov`+`mfence` on most CPUs most of the time, or at least not worse.  In fact, a dummy `lock or  byte [rsp], 0` may be faster than `mfence` when you need a stand-alone barrier like `atomic_thread_fence(mo_seq_cst)` that isn't part of a store.  I thought my linked answer on the first duplicate mentioned all that.